# SwiftUI View is not updating after new data

Tags: swiftui

I have implemented a search feature in my application, and would like for my scrollview element to be populated with results from a local API if and when new data is fetched.

I have a view model I am pulling data from:

```
@MainActor
class BottleViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let bottlesProvider: BottleProvider! = BindexAPI()

    @Published var searchResults = [BottleModel]()
    @Published var searchText: String = ""
    
    func search(q: String) {
        bottlesProvider.getBottleSearch(query: q) {
            switch $0 {
            case let .failure(err):
                print(err)
            case let .success(bottles):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print(self.searchResults.count)
                    self.searchResults = bottles
                    print(self.searchResults.count)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After I enter a query in my textfield and hit enter, I see that when the search is successful the count displays 0 to 1 in the debugger. However, my view is not getting these views.

My assumption is that once the searchResults got updated, anything that is consuming the view model would update, however clearly I am incorrect. Here is the view that I would like to update after a search query.

```
@StateObject private var viewModel = BottleViewModel()
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Search count: \(viewModel.searchResults.count)")
        ForEach(viewModel.searchResults, id: \.self) { bottle in
            NavigationLink(destination: BottleDetailView(bottle: bottle)) {
                BottleListing(bottle: bottle)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
@StateObject private var viewModel = BottleViewModel()
var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField("Search \(viewModel.results.count) bottles", text: $term, onEditingChanged: { isEditing in self.isEditing = isEditing })
                .frame(height: 35)
                .disableAutocorrection(true)
                .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                .padding(7)
                .padding(.horizontal, 25)
                .background(Color.white)
                .accentColor(Color.black)
                .cornerRadius(4)
                .submitLabel(.search)
                .overlay(
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            .padding(.leading, 8)
                        
                        if isEditing {
                            Button(action: {
                                self.term = ""
                                self.isEditing = false
                                UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
                                
                            }) {
                                Image(systemName: "multiply.circle.fill")
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                    .padding(.trailing, 8)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
                .onSubmit {
                    viewModel.search(q: term)
                }
        }
    }
```

Am I missing a property that would tell SwiftUI to update after this array is changed or appended to? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us code where you are calling your `search` method of `BottleViewModel`

Comment: @NiravD I've added it. It's on the onSubmit action of the TextField.

Comment: You are using two different `viewModel` in your views. The lower level view should have: 
`@ObservedObject var viewModel: BottleViewModel` and passed in from the higher level View, 
where you have `@StateObject private var viewModel = BottleViewModel()`. There should be only one `StateObject`.

Comment: Also have a look at this link, it gives you examples of how to use `ObservableObject` and manage data in your app https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Answer (score 1):

Currently you have two `@StateObject private var viewModel = BottleViewModel()` that have no relations to each other.

What you want to achieve is to have **one source of truth** in
`@StateObject var viewModel = BottleViewModel()`. Pass this `viewModel` to other views,
with for example `@ObservedObject` as shown, or `@EnvironmenObject` using `.environmentObject(viewModel)`. So that any change of the `viewModel` is reflected in all views that uses it.

Try this approach, directly passing the `viewModel` to the `other` view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
@StateObject var viewModel = BottleViewModel() // <--- here

var body: some View {
         OtherView(viewModel: viewModel)  // <--- here
        //...
      }
     }


   
struct OtherView: View {
@ObservedObject var viewModel: BottleViewModel  // <--- here

var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField(...)
            //...
        }
      }
     }
```